# PowerShell/winrm cannot connect to server

Tags: powershell, winrm

I'm attempting to setup a remote session in PowerShell to a server but failing to do so and hit a wall in my troubleshooting.

On the server I want to remote to I have done:
* `Enable-PSRemoting`
* Restarted and `winrm quickconfig` to confirm

On my client from where I want to connect to servers I'm attempting to add trusted hosts via:
    `winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="servername"}'`

This fails with: "WSManFault
    Message = The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request."

Server is standalone and not in a domain, does not have firewall enabled (I can RDP to it just fine.)
Right now I'm simply trying to establish a 1to1 connection to perform some tests so there are no certificates included either so I was under the impression that the HTTPS listener would not be needed if I use trusted hosts?

Comment: What is the output of `nslookup servername`? Can you connect via `telnet servername:5985`?

Comment: nslookup shows the DNS server, their names (FQDN) as well as the server in question and their respective IP-address.  
The telnet connection fails saying cannot connect through port 23. (Did have the extra ports on it.)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try `telnet servername 5985` (hostname and port must be separated by whitespace, not a colon).

Comment: Well, it works better, it clears screen and we get the blinking underscore on a blank screen but not much more and entering anything results en a `http/1.1 400 bad request`

Comment: Did you enable WinRM on client as well?

Comment: Check `winrm get winrm/config` on both client and server.

Comment: I did not, to my knowledge the client that manages the servers doesn't need the WinRM configured more than adding trusted hosts? This might be the error otherwise.

Comment: @PatrikPersson But to change configuration on client, you need to enable WinRM service on client, so it can accept configuration change request.

Answer (score 0):

"Did you enable WinRM on client as well? – PetSerAl "

This was the issue, the client trying to manage the server was not configured with WinRM.
Works well with `winrm quickconfig` and then say no to setting up a listener!